# How can I get a CSS from Mapbox

Tags: python, css, data-visualization

To visualise my dataset I need a CSS from the website Mapbox.com where I made my map. I need a access token and that I got, but it's the CSS I can't find and don't know to find.

Could somebody please help?

The link I get is:
https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/darair/ckiuc87o82r3x19sziyygptti/wmts?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiZGFyYWlyIiwiYSI6ImNraXVidGdhbDJ3a3Ayc2xibjR0MThrazcifQ.z__GJc5wJIl3COiFCDY73g

I'm not sure this is the one I need.. I know for a fact it has to have 'css' on the end of the link..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are referring to?
`<link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.0.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />`

If so you can find it in the Mapbox API Documentation located here!
https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/